# Convert substrings of textNode in a span element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem:

with some textNode, I need to convert some substrings in a span element. Is there any jquery function to handle this? or a javascript method?

```html
<p>---------------------Source---------------------</p>
<div id="source">
  abc def ghi google ljm microsoft alpha beta
</div>

<p>----------------------Goal----------------------</p>
<div id="goal">
  abc def ghi <span>google</span> ljm <span>microsoft</span> <span>alpha</span> <span>beta</span>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no built-in method to achieve this, but it's certainly possible if you write the code to do it.

Comment: There is .replace() with or without regex, depending on how many occurances of the substring you need to replace.

Comment: @Isac `wrap()` won't work on individual words within textNodes.

Comment: Thank you guys,

I was behind some standard to do this, as I needed to do this on a rather extensive html page. So I had to do it as efficiently as possible. I built the function based on the colleague's response there and it only takes a few ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.spanIt = function(_array) {
      var html=this.html();
      for(var key in _array){
        html=html.replace(new RegExp(_array[key],"g"), '<span>'+_array[key]+'</span>');
      }
      this.html(html);
      return this;
  };
})( jQuery );


$('#source').spanIt(['google','microsoft', 'alpha', 'beta']);
console.log($('#source').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>---------------------Source---------------------</p>
<div id="source">
  abc def ghi google ljm microsoft alpha beta
</div>

<p>----------------------Goal----------------------</p>
<div id="goal">
  abc def ghi <span>google</span> ljm <span>microsoft</span> <span>alpha</span> <span>beta</span>
</div>
```